# How do i 'ungroup' a grouped data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a large dataframe containing ∼ 100 million observations of stock returns for a given date and an identifier for each specific stock. My problem is that for some stocks at some dates there are missing values in the return column. To set up a small example the data frame looks something like this:

| ID | Date | Return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 1970-01-01 | 0.043 |
| 10001 | 1970-01-02 | 0.023 |
| 10001 | 1970-01-03 | -0.010 |
| 10002 | 1970-01-01 | 0.010 |
| 10002 | 1970-01-02 | NaN |
| 10002 | 1970-01-03 | -0.034 |
| 10003 | 1970-01-01 | 0,040 |
| 10003 | 1970-01-02 | -0.041 |
| 10003 | 1970-01-03 | 0.009 |

I wish to remove all the stocks containing one or more missing values in the return column, which I do by:

```
df = df[df['RET'].notna().groupby('ID').transform('all')]
```

From the data frame example above, this will generate a grouped data frame without stocks having missing values in the return column:

| ID | Date | Return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 1970-01-01 | 0.043 |
|  | 1970-01-02 | 0.023 |
|  | 1970-01-03 | -0.010 |
| 10003 | 1970-01-01 | 0,040 |
|  | 1970-01-02 | -0.041 |
|  | 1970-01-03 | 0.009 |

However, I need to convert the data frame back to being ungrouped again. Do any of you have a solution on how to do this? To specify, I want the data frame to look like this:

| ID | Date | Return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 1970-01-01 | 0.043 |
| 10001 | 1970-01-02 | 0.023 |
| 10001 | 1970-01-03 | -0.010 |
| 10003 | 1970-01-01 | 0,040 |
| 10003 | 1970-01-02 | -0.041 |
| 10003 | 1970-01-03 | 0.009 |

Thank you in advance for any possible solution.

I have already tried using .unstack() and .reset_index() without any luck

Comment: Why are you grouping it instead of just removing the rows with NaN?

Comment: I need to remove the entire group containing one or more NaN values.

Comment: I think you can do this by joining the original df with the grouped df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need grouping. Simple boolean indexing + `.isin()` is enough:

```py
x = df.loc[df['Return'].isna(), 'ID'].unique()
print(df[~df['ID'].isin(x)])
```

Prints:

```
      ID        Date  Return
0  10001  1970-01-01   0.043
1  10001  1970-01-02   0.023
2  10001  1970-01-03  -0.010
6  10003  1970-01-01   0,040
7  10003  1970-01-02  -0.041
8  10003  1970-01-03   0.009
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone should wonder, this could also be fixed by adding ', group_keys=False' to the groupby function:

```
df = df[df['RET'].notna().groupby('ID', group_keys=False).transform('all')]
```